# ASPNET Core 3.1 Identity: Logout user after 10 minutes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using cookie authentication and I want to log the user out after ten minutes if their session is not refreshed.

I have tried to accomplish this using the following options, but it is not working. Using the `PasswordSignInAsync()` method with the `isPersistent` option: When `RememberMe` is true, the cookie expiration time is 14 days; when `RememberMe` is false, it is "Session".

Sign-in Method:

```cs
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
  Input.Email,
  Input.Password, 
  Input.RememberMe, 
  lockoutOnFailure: true
);
```

Startup:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {              
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });

services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's stat.
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you exepecting?  Also how does it "not work"?

Comment: I want to log the user out after ten minutes.

Comment: When someone clicks remember me that is the default behaviour.  Second you have SlidingExpiration to true which means ANY request from the same user will "restart" the timespan.... And how are you "testing" the user has not been logged out?